# Which online/hosted bug tracking tool do you use for your own work and projects?

Tags: issue-tracking, personal-projects

I've accumulated a lot of side projects over the years, which I slowly improve on over time. Whenever I return to one, I take some time reading over text files that include design, recent bugs, next features, etc... that I should be working on - it's not pretty.

I'm looking to switch to something more formal. Ideally, this would be a full featured, online, bug tracking system, which allows for free or nearly free bug tracking for my own projects. Also, ideally this would be doable in a private manner - I don't really want everyone to see my side projects and what a mess I've made of some of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FogCreek offers [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) in a ["Student and Startup edition"](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/StudentAndStartup.html) (anyone can use it), free for up to two uesrs.
Sounds ideal for you, especially combined with Kiln.

I use it the same way for a couple years, and I love it - it works fantastic for me.

Comment: I use this for my both my personal and work projects and it is a really good tool that is well supported.

Comment: You would have had your account atomized if you haven't chosen this answer as the good one ;-)

Answer (score 10):

I've personally used [Hosted Redmine](https://www.hostedredmine.com/), which is a full featured project management tool. Unlike some other free online services, it isn't restricted in features or the number of users.

[image]

Comment: This, but I host my own instance of Redmine.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: Seriously, this needs to be flagged for awesomeness.  I'm sad I can only upvote it once.

Comment: For easier bug reporting try [Usersnap](http://usersnap.com) - you will get screenshots directly into your redmine.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an online repository service (GitHub, Sourceforge, BitBucket, etc.). Most of them offer private repositories and issue tracking.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of [unfuddle.com](http://unfuddle.com).  It contains source control (svn and git), a ticket system, and a simple wiki like system.  It's free for 2 person projects, and reasonably priced for growing teams.

Answer (score 0):

I setup a fedora server with bugzilla tracking.  I also have a central git repository on it where i can check code in/out.  I have automated backup to a secondary drive through Samba to a windows machine, via cron on the server, that is backed up on this drive and then later offsite via Carbonite.

All of that is free EXCEPT for Carbonite.

Answer (score 0):

[BugTracker.net](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html)

BugTracker works very well. You can even set it up to be local or exposed to the web and its very expandable for your needs. I have been using it for about six months now and its been great.

Comment: The list of requirements is staggering... though it might be me prefering lightweight packages.

Answer (score 0):

[BugHerd](http://www.bugherd.com)

BugHerd is a bug tracker specifically for websites. You embed their JavaScript snippet into your site header and users can start logging bugs on your site. This automatically captures a lot of data with bug reports such as browser version, it optionally allows users to pinpoint a location on the page and it takes a screenshot. So always enough data to troubleshoot the issue without needing to contact the client in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 0):

In modern way of working, Github stands out with an excellent way of tracking bugs.[You can checkout the feature page to get a hang of it.](https://github.com/features/projects/issues). Also see [this post](https://github.com/blog/411-github-issue-tracker)

Though it's in an upcoming stage, I strongly recommend [asana](http://asana.com/). You may lose certain kind of controls when comparing with legacy bug trakcing systems but they laid right the fundamentals like Projects, tags, assignment, collaboration. [see help article here](http://help.asana.com/customer/portal/articles/119165-how-to-use-asana-for-bug-tracking)